# How to display XDebug errors only to my IP address?

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

I'm in a non-ideal situation where I have to debug a website a live website running PHP5.4 on a LAMP stack.

After enabling XDebug in php.ini and setting `display_errors` to true, I get nicely formatter HTML output for bugs.

However, I'd like to be the only person to be able to see these bugs.

I understand there is some sort of extension for IDEs that allow you do that, but I'm a bit confused about the whole thing.

I looked into `xdebug.remote_host` but couldn't get it to work.

Is there a way to make errors show up only to requests coming from my IP address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing you want to do has nothing to with XDebug... turn `display_errors` off.  It sounds counter-intuitive but what `display_errors` actually does is configure whether or not the errors should be sent to STDOUT or STDERR from PHP.

If you turn off `display_errors`, you can then configure PHP to log them instead.  Then, just SSH into your box and tail that log file while you track down the problem.

Comment: Yeah that ended up being really confusing. Thanks for the help.